# How to read file zip using JSZip in Firefox SDK

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jszip

I want to make addons to work to extract the zip file locally like this ([here](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples/read-local-file-api.html)). But I have a problem when making use firefox SDK. Which can not be read zip because somethings wrong when get path of **fileinput** and errors unsupported format because **dataType** not ArrayBuffer.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="import" class="hide" />
```

**myscript.js**

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('import');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var zipFileToLoad = fileInput.files[0];
    var tampJson = [];
    JSZip.loadAsync(zipFileToLoad)
            .then(function(zip) {
                console.dir(zip);
                zip.forEach(function (relativePath, zipEntry) {
                    if(zipEntry.dosPermissions == null){
                        alert('Permissions trouble !')
                    }
                    if(typeof(zipEntry['_data']['compressedContent']) != 'undefined'){
                        //var text = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(zipEntry['_data']['compressedContent']));
                        var text = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(zipEntry['_data']['compressedContent']);
                        var dec = text.toString();

                        var json = JSON.parse(dec);
                        if(json != null){
                            var keys = ['name', 'description', 'data', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
                            keys.forEach(function(key){
                                if (key in json){
                                    if(key == keys[keys.length - 1]){
                                        tampJson.push(json);
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    dialog({
                                        title: "Warning",
                                        description: "<b>Wrong format, </b> are you sure to continue?",
                                        yesButton: "yes",
                                        cancelButton: "No",
                                        yesCallback: function() {
                                            $(this).closest('.overlay').removeClass("active");
                                        },
                                        cancelCallback: function() {
                                            $(this).closest('.overlay').removeClass("active");
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }else{
                            alert('format parse gagal');
                        }
                    }
                });
                if(tampJson.length > 0){
                    saveByImport(tampJson, 0);
                }else{
                    alert('Oops file empty');
                }
            }, function (e) {
                alert('Oops import fail '+ e);
            });
```

Can't error in console. I just can not ArrayBuffer from fileinput. 
This script can work in chrome extension but not work in firefox sdk.
So please help me for solving this problem.

Comment: How specifically does this not work? What are you expecting to happen? What happens? What messages do you see in the browser console? What file are you attempting to read? etc.  Please provide a **complete** [mcve]. That means enough code to actually have an add-on. While, technically all code needs to be in the question, even a link to a GitHub repository helps. Whatever problem you are having can easily depend on so much more than the code you have provided, particularly in an add-on. In general, we need to be able to duplicate whatever problem you are having in order to help you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include:  •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it* **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: *How to create a [mcve], [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you @Makyen i'm already edit my question. I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1):

I used an older version of jszip in my addon here. You can use the jszip from my repository and use it the way I did. See here - https://github.com/Noitidart/Chrome-Store-Foxified/blob/master/resources/scripts/MainWorker.js#L195